# Select from xls file where row is not null

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

While reading data from xls file, using oldedb as follows with no problem

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + fileID + "]", oledbConn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
```

But I want to extend the select statement to only select rows of a certain column that is not null WHERE ... IS NOT NULL, what is that ... suppose to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the option `HDR=YES` in your connection string
then use the column title in the `WHERE` clause to specify the column.
If not, then use `F1...FN` to specify the column.

Select query for `HDR=NO` (and first column):

```
SELECT * FROM [" + fileID + "] WHERE [F1] IS NOT NULL
```

Select query for `HDR=YES`:

```
SELECT * FROM [" + fileID + "] WHERE [YourColumnTitle] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Works great thanks. I used HDR=YES and Title of Column. Just a small question, can I use HDR = YES yet still use some type of index, and give the column number instead of name of the column.

Comment: @Karaman: You could realize this by querying the schema table (use GetOleDbSchemaTable()) for COLUMN_NAME and ORDINAL_POSITION.